# Why is .find() more effective than a selector?

Tags: jquery

webstorm (intellij) says

```
$('#cards').find('.box .row')
```

is more effective than

```
$('#cards .box .row')
```

But.. why? I would had thought it would be other way actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [quick jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/single-selector-vs-jquery-find), it's actually quicker without using the `.find()` method.

It's entirely possible that the results may differ depending on your browser, but it seems like a single query is significantly faster.

Results:

```
// Fastest
// 112,996 operations
var text = $('#cards .box .row').text();

// 39% slower
// 69,350
var text = $('#cards').find('.box .row').text();
```

[image]

Comment: Wow for me the difference is even higher, way higher. That's impressing. Thank you for this insight. Still wondering why jetbrains claims my query would be inefficient. Anyway, this answer goes accept ;)