# Is it more efficient to use find() rather than > for child selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, I thought it will be more efficient to find a child DOM with a specific selector with **Implementation 1** as below:

```
var $dataTable = $('#' + tabId + ' > div.container > div.dataTableContainer > table.dataTable');
```

But one friend of mine told me that it will be more efficient when using
**Implementation 2** as below:

```
var dataTable = $('#' + tabId).find('table.dataTable');
```

Referenced to [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010119/why-is-find-more-effective-than-a-selector), I found the Implementation 2 may be less efficient than:

```
var $dataTable = $('#' + tabId + ' div.container div.dataTableContainer  table.dataTable');
```

But will **Implementation 2** be more efficient than **Implementation 1**?

Comment: First code runned by native javascript search but second is jquery search.

Comment: Go for find, in all perf tests of jquery the results are best, faster than context like $('table.dataTable', $('#' + tabId)) or  an selector.

Comment: @Mohammad No, both of them are using Sizzle, the jQuery selector engine.

Comment: no. 1sd gives `#tabId > .cont > .data > .table` ,2nd gives `#tabId .table`

Comment: @BenM I think jquery write first selector in javascript `querySelectorAll()` and return result of it.

Comment: @Rajesh '>' means direct child, not first child

Comment: `>` means direct descendents only, while `.find()` is the equivalent of `" "` (space) - which will search all descendents.  The equivalent of `>` is `.children()`. If you have a large hierarchy of DOM elements under your top level node, `>` will be faster.

Comment: Can uou include `html` at Question?

Comment: this should show the diffence between selectors: https://www.sitepoint.com/jsperf1/

Comment: You friend probably confused the fact than `var dataTable = $('#' + tabId).find('table.dataTable');` is faster than `var dataTable = $('table.dataTable', '#' + tabId);`. Your best bet here, if your HTML markup regading direct child doesn't really matter is to use: `$('#' + tabId + ' table.dataTable');` this would allow sizzle jQuery to use internally `document.querySelectorAll()`. And if you really care about any performance (you shoudln't that much at this point!), test code in jsPerf.com

Comment: Sorry, it is: [jsPerf.co](https://jsperf.co/)

Comment: What is "effective" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`document.querySelector()` with direct descendant selector `>` is fastest, `.find()` is slowest.

```js
var tabId = "abc";

console.time(".find()");
var $dataTable = $('#' + tabId).find('table.dataTable');
console.timeEnd(".find()");

console.time("jQuery(), >");
var $dataTable = $('#' + tabId + ' > div.container > div.dataTableContainer > table.dataTable');
console.timeEnd("jQuery(), >");

console.time("document.querySelector()");
var $dataTable = document.querySelector('#' + tabId + ' div.container div.dataTableContainer  table.dataTable');
console.timeEnd("document.querySelector()");

console.time("document.querySelector(), >");
var $dataTable = document.querySelector('#' + tabId + ' >  div.container > div.dataTableContainer > table.dataTable');
console.timeEnd("document.querySelector(), >");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dataTableContainer">
      <table class="dataTable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: But as a side note,  `document.querySelector()` matches only one node.

Comment: Note, OP did not include `html` at Question. Or specify if multiple elements were expected to be matched.

Comment: @Kaiido `>` is faster than without. `.querySelector()` or `.querySelectorAll()` is faster than jQuery methods.

Comment: OP also is asking specifically for jQuery optimisation tips. Native javascript will always be faster

Comment: @kevmc _"OP also is asking specifically for jQuery optimisation tips"_ ? The jQuery test is at stacksnippets. `.find()` is slower than `jQuery()` with direct descendant selector `>`. Not certain what you are expecting at tests? Use `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()` if performance is requirement.

Comment: @guest271314 sorry - my bad

Comment: Your test is still biased by the fact than using `document.querySelector()` you return DOM node, not jq set. So you should still wrap the result in a jq object to more relevant comparaison. BUT it would still be lightly fatser but nothing than would justify the use of it, imho. Better is to get readable code than some code which would let you win micro seconds

Comment: @A.Wolff Actually, OP does not use the term "efficient"; but rather, "effective". Though not sure what "effective" means to OP within the context of the Question?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding and my poor English. It is supposed to mean "efficient".

Answer (score 3):

**My *guess*:**

Under the hood `$('#XXX  whatever')` does a native `document.queryselectorAll()`, which will check **all of the elements within the document** to see if they match '`#xxx whatever`'

`$('#XXX').find('whatever')` first does a `document.getElementById('XXX')`, finding the element with `id="XXX"` and then does a `queryselectorAll()` within that element, so has fewer child elements to test and see if they match '`whatever`'

But this guess is completely negated by real data - see the answer by @guest271314

Comment: QSA doesn't do that in any browser I'm aware of: it'll look up all `whatever` elements (from cache), and then for each walk up the ancestor chain to see if they are a descendent of an element matching `#XXX`. Browsers' selector matching is well optimised!