# jquery get the first element in document order

Tags: jquery, performance, find, selector

Jquery get the first element with a selector:

```
aElement.find(".ui-foo").first();
```

If the document is big and has many element with ui-foo, the performance is not
ideal. JQuery should stop searching after finding the first one. Is there a better way to get the first element?

Comment: Maybe `aElement.find(".ui-foo:first")` using the [jQuery `:first` selector'](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)? I am not sure if that is more performant though because internally it is probably doing the same thing. You could always check out [jspeft.com](https://jsperf.com/) to compare performance.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Note, `:first` is a jQuery selector, not a `css` selector, save for `css` `@page` pseudo class.

Comment: @guest271314 - Huh? I never said it was a CSS selector... I clearly stated that it was a jQuery selector and I linked to the relevant jQuery documentation.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Did not state that you said `:first` was a `css` selector. jQuery selectors are generally require greater time to return result than `css` selector.

Comment: @guest271314 - Oh, I misunderstood. You are definitely right on that one.

Comment: @JoshCrozier The only way to be certain is to run the tests for each possible selector or pattern. Though present Question does not contain `html` to run tests according to description of `document`. We could create a mock test, though should we have to? The actual `html` could be different from what we create. `document.querySelector("parent > child")` would probably take least amount of time [Is it more efficient to use find() rather than > for child selector in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993827/is-it-more-efficient-to-use-find-rather-than-for-child-selector-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be faster not sure though. Didn't test it yet.

```
aElement.find(".ui-foo")[0]
```

Comment: Using `.find()` would not decrease time to return result. `jQuery()` returns results in less time than `.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for performance point of view and considering you are not able to add id to that field,you must use plain javascript for this particular scenario.
So using

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-foo'),
requiredDiv=divs[0];
```

Will be more performance optimised.
Always remember: using any library for such simple actions will add overhead for computation.