# Is it more performant to cache a selector in a function if that function's called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, caching

Ok I think I know the answer to this, looking to confirm. So I have a selector that's only used once, but it's used inside a function that's called several times. From a performance perspective, since that selector is re-searched-for each time the function is called, it's probably (albeit marginally) better to cache the selector?

In other words, the below...

```
function testFunction() {
  alert($("#input").val())
}

$("#a").click(function() {
  testFunction()
})

$("#b").click(function() {
  testFunction()
})

$("#c").click(function() {
  testFunction()
})
```

...is not as performant as the below

```
input = $("#input")

function testFunction() {
  alert(input.val())
}

$("#a").click(function() {
  testFunction()
})

$("#b").click(function() {
  testFunction()
})

$("#c").click(function() {
  testFunction()
})
```

Comment: You can cache jQuery object once to avoid calling `jQuery()` multiple times. You can also determine, without speculation, which approach is more "performant" by checking the total time necessary to call the function using each pattern, see [Is it more efficient to use find() rather than > for child selector in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993827/is-it-more-efficient-to-use-find-rather-than-for-child-selector-in-jquery/). Without benchmarks the inquiry is based on guessing, not facts.

Comment: If its about performance, try `.click(testFunction)`. You are defining 3 anonymous function with same signature. You should use 1 names function and use it in all handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, `jQuery()` call completes in less total time than variable reference to jQuery object. Last run logged

- jQuery(): 16.580ms
- cached jQuery() object: 22.885ms

```js
(function() {

  function testFunction() {
    $("#input").val()
  }

  console.time("jQuery()");

  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    testFunction()
  }
  
  console.timeEnd("jQuery()");
  
})();

(function() {

  let input = $("input");

  function testFunction() {
    input.val()
  }

  console.time("cached jQuery() object");

  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    testFunction()
  }
  
  console.timeEnd("cached jQuery() object");
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input>
```

Comment: @james Interestingly, when using jQuery version 3.1.1 the duration between the two patterns increases by approximately two seconds, where `jQuery()` call still completes before "cached" jQuery object reference.

Comment: WOW that's very surprising! thanks for doing this, and showing me how to run a test like this myself. any idea why this might be true? it's not very logical admittedly...

Comment: @james Not sure how logic is involved. Perhaps presumption. The facts are clear from perspective here. Not certain about exact cause; cost of object lookup? Though try to avoid speculation, here. You can file an issue at https://github.com/jquery/jquery; to ask the authors and maintainers of jQuery library to provide their assessment of the patterns and raw data derived therefrom. Probably not on-topic for the repository itself, though interesting empirical results nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right the second one is more efficient than the first one because

In the first one to select the input filled first it going to find the input
field then it select that input field,And this will happen each time of function call.

But in second case the selector is select once when the page is loaded the it refers that selector through the variable and will not go to find that input field in each call.That why 2nd one is more efficiency.

```
        <input value='Value' id='input'><br>
        <span id='tt'>dssd</span><br>
        <span id='t1'></span><br>
        <span id='t2'></span>
```

And Jquery:-

```
 function testFunction1() {
        var t=$("#input").val()
        $("#tt").html(t);
    }
    console.time("jQuery() object");
    var t1=performance.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        testFunction1()
    }
    console.timeEnd("jQuery() object");

    var t2=performance.now();
    t2=t2-t1;
    $("#t1").html('Without selector variable:- '+t2);
    var input = $("input");
    function testFunction2() {
        var t=input.val();
        $("#tt").html(t);
    }
     t1=performance.now();
    console.time("cached jQuery() object");
    for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        testFunction2()
    }
     t2=performance.now();
    console.timeEnd("cached jQuery() object");
    t2=t2-t1;
    $("#t2").html('With selector variable:- '+t2);
```

Just Check here:-[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Bibhudatta_sahoo/7k9oquuk/2/)

Comment: _"Yes you are right the second one is more efficient than the first one"_ That is not accurate, as demonstrated at stacksnippets at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44427954/. _"That why 2nd one is more efficiency."_ Can you  reproduce the second pattern completing in less time than first pattern at stacksnippets, jsfiddle, plnkr or jsperf?

Comment: _"But why you say like that"_ Say like what? The facts? Can you show and prove to substantiate the proposition that _"the second one is more efficient than the first one"_? Or, are you merely speculating as to which pattern is "more efficient"? What do you mean by "more efficient"?

Comment: Just check this https://jsfiddle.net/Bibhudatta_sahoo/ukscnxme/6/
then only we get why i am say it more efficient.

Comment: You should post the code at a stacksnippets at your Answer