# Shorthand to get jquery object from event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, jquery-events

Is there a way to get a jquery object back from an event to reduce the amount of `$(e.target)` that has to be done?

For example:

```
$(document).on('click',"div", function(e){
        $(e.target).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

could be written as

```
$(document).on('click',"div", function(e){
        e.JQUERY_target.css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Is there a way to get a jquery object from the event without having to convert it?

Comment: `could be written as` - can it?

Comment: @JaromandaX could be written as what?

Comment: you said it, I was asking if that was a statement or a question :p

Comment: The Question as is does not present a clear problem statement if the goal is solely to not use `jQuery()` function, though still use `jQuery()` function. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm wondering if jquery modifies the event to include a target that is already cast as a jquery object so that the user doesn't have to cast it as a jquery object

Comment: @Alexis No jQuery does not provide a jQuery object at the `event` object itself by default. You would need to create a function which implements that functionality. For what purpose though?

Comment: @guest271314 got it

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get a jquery object back from an event to reduce the
>   amount of `$(e.target)` that has to be done?

Yes. Do not use jQuery for the task. jQuery is not necessary at all for the specific requirement

```
$(document).on("click", "div", function(e){
  e.target.style.color = "red";    
});
```

Comment: I see.  The color is a simple example of what I'm trying to do.  I want the target as a jquery object.

Comment: Then you need to use jQuery or cache the selector. Though a cached selector does not mean anything in particular [Is it more performant to cache a selector in a function if that function's called multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427606/is-it-more-performant-to-cache-a-selector-in-a-function-if-that-functions-calle)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` if you want to use jQuery methods. Or `e.target` if you want to use vanilla JS methods.

Using $(this) with jQuery methods:

```js
$(document).on('click', "div", function(e) {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click Me</div>
```

Using `e.target` with vanilla JS methods:

```js
$(document).on('click', "div", function(e) {
  e.target.style.color = 'red';
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click Me</div>
```

Comment: That results in the same call to `jQuery()`

Comment: I see but it also needs that conversion with `$()` which I am trying to get around if possible with a shorthand

Comment: So you don't want to use `e.target` or `$(this)`?

Comment: @Alexis Why are you trying to "get around" using jQuery if you are already using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can harness the awesome power of `this`!

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Where `$(this)` is the current object you are running code on. In this case, you're saying that whenever a `div` that is a child of `document` is clicked on, you want to run the given code on it. Thus, this is the div that was clicked on.

Comment: That results in the same call to `jQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

No, events give you only DOM objects. If you want to use jQuery, `$()` them.