# 'each' and 'addClass workaround' which is faster and easy for file to load jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each

This is more a knowledge question for me to attain some clarification regarding this `function`. **1st** method is done by my colleague and **2nd** one by me. I am not a fan of `each` loop and sometimes I use it as a need, what I like is to manipulate elements and work with it(2nd Method).

*My question is that which is faster **1s**t or **2nd** method?*
and can we use `foreach` for this function and will it be better.?

```js
$('select.test').on('change', function() {
  var option_val = $(this).val(),
    option_data_val = $(this).data('id');
  $('select.test').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('id') != option_data_val) {
      $(this).find('option[value="' + option_val + '"]').addClass('gotIt');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.gotIt{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_parent">
  <select class="test" data-id="1">
 <option value="1" class="hi">1</option>
 <option value="2" class="hi">2</option>
 <option value="3" class="hi">3</option>
 <option value="4" class="hi">4</option>
 <option value="5" class="hi">5</option>
 <option value="6" class="hi">6</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="select_parent">
  <select class="test" data-id="2">
 <option value="1" class="hi">1</option>
 <option value="2" class="hi">2</option>
 <option value="3" class="hi">3</option>
 <option value="4" class="hi">4</option>
 <option value="5" class="hi">5</option>
 <option value="6" class="hi">6</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="select_parent">
  <select class="test" data-id="3">
 <option value="1" class="hi">1</option>
 <option value="2" class="hi">2</option>
 <option value="3" class="hi">3</option>
 <option value="4" class="hi">4</option>
 <option value="5" class="hi">5</option>
 <option value="6" class="hi">6</option>
</select>
</div>
```

```js
$('select.test').on('change', function() {
  var option_val = $(this).val();
  $('select.test').addClass('dummy-class');
  $(this).closest('.select_parent').find('select.test').removeClass('dummy-class');
  $('select.test option').removeClass('gotIt');
  $('select.test.dummy-class option[value='+option_val+']').addClass('gotIt');
});
```

```css
.gotIt{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_parent">
  <select class="test" data-id="1">
 <option value="1" class="hi">1</option>
 <option value="2" class="hi">2</option>
 <option value="3" class="hi">3</option>
 <option value="4" class="hi">4</option>
 <option value="5" class="hi">5</option>
 <option value="6" class="hi">6</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="select_parent">
  <select class="test" data-id="2">
 <option value="1" class="hi">1</option>
 <option value="2" class="hi">2</option>
 <option value="3" class="hi">3</option>
 <option value="4" class="hi">4</option>
 <option value="5" class="hi">5</option>
 <option value="6" class="hi">6</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="select_parent">
  <select class="test" data-id="3">
 <option value="1" class="hi">1</option>
 <option value="2" class="hi">2</option>
 <option value="3" class="hi">3</option>
 <option value="4" class="hi">4</option>
 <option value="5" class="hi">5</option>
 <option value="6" class="hi">6</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: _"My question is that which is faster 1st or 2nd method?"_ Have you performed the benchmarks yourself?

Comment: @guest271314, No - actually is it there a way to do that.?

Comment: See [Is it more efficient to use find() rather than > for child selector in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993827/is-it-more-efficient-to-use-find-rather-than-for-child-selector-in-jquery/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share a piece of code with you & might be helpful to other too.
You can see the time for completing a set of code. Below I have shared a code on you console you can see the time required for each process(on each event: Change).

```
<script>
//  On 1 set of your code
$('select.test').on('change', function() {
    start_time = new Date().getTime();
    var option_val = $(this).val(),
    option_data_val = $(this).data('id');
    $('select.test').each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('id') != option_data_val) {
            $(this).find('option[value="' + option_val + '"]').addClass('gotIt');
        }
    });
    request_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
    console.log(request_time);
});
</script>

<script>
//  On 2 set of your code
$('select.test').on('change', function() {
    start_time = new Date().getTime();
    var option_val = $(this).val();
    $('select.test').addClass('dummy-class');
    $(this).closest('.select_parent').find('select.test').removeClass('dummy-class');
    $('select.test option').removeClass('gotIt');
    $('select.test.dummy-class option[value='+option_val+']').addClass('gotIt');
    request_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
    console.log(request_time);
});
</script>
```

And, I have also note that your two different code sections(1. using `each()` & 2. without `each()` ) are not working in similar way that you have expecting. So that may also effect time. 1st one, keeps the `.gotIt` class even we change select value whereas other does not do so.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in speed should be so negligible between the two methods that you don't have to worry about it. You could do some deep bench marking across several different platforms, browsers versions, etc. but unless you need to get really picky about processing time, I can't see how it would be worth the effort.

As for the loops, it's frequently easier to build select inputs using a loop as long as the values, etc. are predictable.